# Looking for something similar to Path.Combine to navigate folders

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

A colleague of mine is looking for a method in System.IO that will do this:

```
var path1 = "c:\\temp\\foo\\bar";
var path2 = "..\\..\\foo2\\file.txt";

var path3 = Path.Combine2(path1, path2);
// path3 = "c:\\temp\\foo2\\file.txt"
```

Is there anything in System.IO to do this type of combining, or will he have to write his own method? I couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var path1 = "c:\\temp\\foo\\bar";
var path2 = "..\\..\\foo2\\file.txt";

var path3 = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path1, path2)).Normalize();
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) Is the Normalize() just to make sure the string is easier to analyze later (ie doesn't contain un-normalized backslashes that a regex may miss) or does it have any other function?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured he would have to do. I'll just wrap it in a utility method for him.

Comment: `Normalize()` is used for unicode strings, it helps make sure they can be compared. I'm using it as an habit actually, `Path.GetFullPath` does the job here.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it;

```
var path3 =  Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path1, path2));
```